# How can I reload shipping methods when custom checkbox address attribute clicked?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, shipping-address

Is there a way to update the shipping methods when clicked on my custom checkbox attribute? 
When I change the city or the postal code the shipping method reloads but not with my custom checkbox.

Thanks!

[image: I]

Comment: Hello, Please give me your attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please follow below path and add your custom attribute add in this js file.

vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules/tablerate.js

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return {
        /**
         * @return {Object}
         */
        getRules: function () {
            return {
                'postcode': {
                    'required': true
                },
                'country_id': {
                    'required': true
                },
                'region_id': {
                    'required': true
                },
                'region_id_input': {
                    'required': true
                },
                'attribute_name':{
                  'required': true
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

After a change in this file please override in your module and please change add in pub static file.

Comment: Thanks Tushar but this doesn´t make my shipping methods reload :(